# Error using express routes method in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to structure my NodeJS API in a different way, but I'm getting the following error when trying to import my routes:

> /Users/pato/Documents/nodejs-bp-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139
>   debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
>                                    ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

**express.js file**

```
.
.
app.use(cors());
app.use(config.api.prefix, apiRoutes());
```

**API routes/index.js**

```
const todo = require('../api/routes/todo');
const express = require('express');   
const apiRoutes = () => {
   const app = express.Router();
   todo(app);
   return app();
};

    module.exports = apiRoutes;
```

**todo.js route**

```
const todo = router => {
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!' });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return app();` should just be `return app;` (with no parentheses). A router is called as a function by express when handling a request, not during setup.

Comment: omg, i fixed right before you posted the answer haha thanks so much! that's what it was!